# Android Studio: How build signed apk with different package names

Tags: android, android-studio, package

I've been told that Android Studio makes building multiple package names easy.
(It is a pain in Eclipse). I heard it is very easy as selecting from the dropdown list. However, I cannot find how to do it.

I want to build one package name for paid version another for free version.

All I found is:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        versionCode 10
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName "com.example.flavor1"
            versionCode 20
        }

        flavor2 {
            packageName "com.example.flavor2"
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
}
```

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations

However, I still cannot sign an apk with different package name.

Comment: Are you changing the `Build Variant` each time that you're building?